# output an object to a file using python

Tags: python, file-io

I want to know how i can store a class object in a file so as to retrive it later. eg) I have a stack class and i need to store the object of that class to retrive it later. I tried the following:

```
output_file=open('hello.txt','w')
output_file.write(x)
```

Where x is the object of the stack class. The whole stack program works well and when i come to this storing part, i get an error as:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "class.py", line 32, in <module>
    output_file.write(x)
TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

How can i correct this mistake? what is the best way to store?

Comment: What is in the stack? What do you expect the contents of the file to look like, or does it matter?

Comment: it doesnt matter what the contents of the file look like. I just need a way to store it and get it back later

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest is to use the [`pickle`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) module.

There are some [examples in the manual](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#example).

Answer (score 1):

Either use `pickle` as suggested or coerce the object to a `str`, which is what `write` is expecting.

Note, if you decide to coerce to a `str` and want to recover the object, you'll need to overwrite `__str__` in the object you are serializing to output enough data to reconstruct the object.

Comment: Just blindly calling `str` on things is definitely not going to put a **useful** string into the file.

Comment: @Aswin, yes, check the documentation for full details.